# Mounting NFS throws System Error: Success

Tags: server, mount, nfs

I have built an NFS Server using [NFS4J](https://github.com/dCache/nfs4j) on MacOS, my code is identical to the example in the Readme. I have created a Ubuntu VM using multipass, and added the following lines to my exportfile:

```
/Users/user/Documents 192.168.64.3(rw, sync, no_root_squash, no_subtree_check)
```

Then, mounting using NFS4, throws an error, because MacOS only supports NFS Version 3 or 2 Servers. If I try to mount using this command though:

```
ubuntu@primary:~$ sudo mount -o nfsvers=3 192.168.1.17:/Users/user/Documents /nfs/my_dir
mount.nfs: mount to NFS server '192.168.1.17:/Users/ziadmalik/Documents' failed: System Error: Success
```

I am confused, did it fail successfully or what am I supposed to take away from this?

Note: This does not show in the dd command.

Comment: Please don't [crosspost](https://superuser.com/questions/1742324/mounting-nfs-throws-system-error-success).

Comment: @Jos Oops, sorry. Did not know where it fits.

Comment: Thats gotta be the funniest error ive ever seen.

Comment: @TardisGuy I know, right?